# Jquery ajax function works locally but not on server

Tags: jquery, ajax

please i need a little help with this as i've been trying all day to figure it out and i couldn't...

So , this function here:

```
function doSearch(){
        $('#dg').datagrid('load',{
            search: $('#search').val()
        });
        $('#dg').datagrid('reload');
    }
```

Works perfectly on localhost but not on server, i can't find any error, please someone give me an idea...
I use jquery-1.6.min.js and olso jquery.easyui.
I tested, the same perfect code works on local but not in live web.

Thanks

CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var url;
        function newUser(){
            $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','New User');
            $('#fm').form('clear');
            url = 'save_er.php';
        }
        function editUser(){
            var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
            if (row){
                $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','Edit User');
                $('#fm').form('load',row);
                url = 'update_er.php?id='+row.id;
            }
        }
        function doSearch(){
        $('#dg').datagrid('load',{
            search: $('#search').val()
        });
        $('#dg').datagrid('reload');
    }

        function saveUser(){
            $('#fm').form('submit',{
                url: url,
                onSubmit: function(){
                    return $(this).form('validate');
                },
                success: function(result){
                    var result = eval('('+result+')');
                    if (result.success){
                        $('#dlg').dialog('close');      // close the dialog
                        $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                    } else {
                        $.messager.show({
                            title: 'Error',
                            msg: result.msg
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        function removeUser(){
    var rows = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelections');
    $.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure you want to remove this user?',function(r){
        if (r){
            for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {        
                    $.post('remove_er.php',{id:rows[i].id},function(result){
                        if (!result.success){
                            $.messager.show({   // show error message
                                title: 'Error',
                                msg: result.msg
                            });
                        }
                    },'json');
            }
            $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data only once after deleting selected objects
        }
    });
}
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you provide some more code? And you are sure your console doesn't show any errors?

Comment: THANKS, I'VE ADDED SOME MORE CODE, THE STRANGE THING IS THAT ALL OTHER FUNCTIONS WORK PERFECTLY EXCEPT THE DOSEARCH ONE

Answer (score 0):

If it works on the local but not in live web then the problem should be with your referencing of your jquery-1.6.min.js and jquery.easyui files. Check to see if they are referenced properly.

Comment: Maybe there's something to do with the .load function? all the other functions work fine, please help